# How can I do Multiple Price fields for Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, customization

How can I make it so Magento 2 has multiple price fields?

The idea is so each product has 3 price fields.

UK
EU
US

The client wants to control this manually for each product

So whilst product A is 
UK - 1.00
EU- 1.19
USA - 3.00

She may want Product B as
UK 1.00
EU 1.63
USA 2.99

The client can then do a csv product sheet which would look like

ID | Product title | SKU | UK | EU | USA

So these Fields would also be in the admin end under the product and then on the frontend I would hook into a Geo locate extension to do something like
IF Geolocate is UK then show UK_PRICE

Just unsure how to accomplish this in the backend.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd actually be better off with creating a separate store for each region, assigning them all roughly the same design templates and a subdomain such as uk.sitename.com, us.sitename.com and eu.sitename.com which can be redirected to based on geolocation. Then the prices can be edited by store view.

Comment: If we did it this way, could each store share the same database? I will ask the client if this is something she would want to do. As this sounds a lot more logical.

Comment: You can also achieve this using product attributes as well. You can create 3 different product attributes for maintaining the price, on the frontend when a product will be ordered then you are supposed to apply the price in the order based on the region it is ordered from.

Comment: Each store can share the same database yeah - the way that we currently have it is that every one of our stores goes through the same magento installation. You can simply add the product to all websites and then when you're viewing the product in the backend you can change your view to the store you'd like to edit it for and change the price